# Apartment mgt breaking lease before my move in

Tags: residential-lease, breaking-the-lease

I signed a lease agreement with an apartment community last week. The start date of my lease is Nov 10,2019. I received a call from community management today telling me that the apartment we signed up for will not be available. They told me that the current residents decided to break their lease earlier and that is how the management offered us that place. Today the residents called them and said that they no longer wish to break their lease. Therefore I have to look into other options.

Now this sounds unreasonable. Why should I be at the receiving end of such a convoluted situation between the current resident and management? Is there anything that I can do in this regard.

Comment: If you signed a lease agreement, you have a contract.  What does the contract say?
They must honor their end of the contract.

Comment: No doubt the lease has a clause which covers their responsibility in the case that the apartment is not available at the time of move in.

Answer (score 3):

### Your contract is the only relevant one in your relationship with your landlord

If they have broken it you can sue for damages. However, you have to actually read the lease to see if they have broken it - if they are doing something the lease permits, they haven’t broken it.